# Find norm of vector given in terms of an orthonormal frame

Tags: linear-algebra

> For a positively-oriented orthonormal frame $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$, let $a= 2e_1 +3e_2-4e_3$ and $b=e_1-e_2+3e_3$. Determine $|a|$ and $a^{-1}$?

I got the magnitude of $a$ to be 32 by taking the square root of all the coefficients squared. The $a^{-1}$ is bit of a problem for me

Comment: im trying to put the right math symbols up

Comment: I have edited the TeX, but I cannot make sense of what you are writing. You are not using $b$ in your question, and what is $a^{-1}$ if $a$ is a vector?

Comment: if a is a vector, according to my notes then a inverse is equal to a divided by the magnitude of a squared. I am lost at that point

Comment: thanks for the edit. I am still learning to correctly do what you just did

Comment: the b in this must be part of my 2nd part to this question

Comment: Ok, then I think the notation $a^{-1}$ is awful, but it makes a bit of sense because $\langle a,a^{-1}\rangle =1$; but it is a very poor concept of inverse.

Comment: can you check out my part 2 to this question? I think my professor made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
$$
|a|=\langle a,a\rangle^{1/2}=(2^2+3^2+(-4)^2)^{1/2}=(4+9+16)^{1/2}=\sqrt{29}.
$$
And (I still think this is an awful notation)
$$
a^{-1}=\frac a{|a|^2}=\frac a{29}=\frac2{29}e_1+\frac 3{29}e_2-\frac 4{29}e_3.
$$

Comment: Oh, I was not using my e as part of my answer. I had the fraction part only which why I was confused. you right, the notation is awful. What notation would you suggest to use?

Comment: I don't really think that $a/|a|^2$ deserves a particular notation. I would just write it that way: $a/|a|^2$ or $\frac a{|a|^2}$.

Comment: I see. thanks for the insight